# vs2013 create mapping to new source location using powershell

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2013

I have been trying to automate the local setup Visual Studio (2013) workspace. I have been able to make the connection to the source location using PowerShell, but I cannot get the local mapping to apply. If I manually map the source location, I can get the local mapping to apply with PowerShell.  I have borrowed heavily from other Stack Overflow threads, but I cannot seam to find a way to map the TFS server and map the local paths to the workspace.  Thanks!

```
clear host

[string]$TfsUrl = 'https://xxxx.visualstudio.com'

'.Client', '.VersionControl.Client', '.VersionControl.Common', '.WorkItemTracking.Client', '.Build.Client', '.Build.Common' |
ForEach-Object {
    Add-Type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.TeamFoundation$_, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
}

try
{
    $uri = New-Object System.Uri -ArgumentList $TfsUrl
    $credentialProvider = new-object Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.UICredentialsProvider
    $collection = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory]::GetTeamProjectCollection($uri, $credentialProvider)    
    $collection.Authenticate()

    if ($collection.HasAuthenticated)
    {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green 'Connection to TFS Successful'
        $tfs = '' | Select-Object Collection, VersionControlServer, WorkItemStore, BuildServer, IdentityManagementService        
        $tfs.Collection = $collection

        $tfs
    }
}
catch
{
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red $_.Exception.Message
    Write-Host
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red 'Failed to connect to TFS'
}

$tfsServer = "https://xxxx.visualstudio.com"
$computerName = [system.environment]::machinename
$folderName = "C:\VSTS_WB\xxxx.DuckCreek"; 

$dir = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\'
Set-Alias tf "$dir\tf.exe"

new-item -itemtype directory -path $folderName -force

cd $folderName

tf workfold "$/xxxx.DuckCreek" $folderName /map

tf workfold "$/xxxx.DuckCreek/BR1/Policy/Source" "C:\Program Files\Duck Creek Technologies" /map

tf workfold "$/xxxx.DuckCreek/BR1/Policy/Source/Shared.x86" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Duck Creek Technologies" /map

tf workfold "$/xxxx.DuckCreek/BR1/Billing/Source" "C:\Program Files\Duck Creek Technologies Billing" /map
```

Comment: Can you provide what you've tried so far in script?

Comment: Sorry, I should have included that initially.  It has been added to my question.

Comment: instead of making the workfolder immediately I'd check to see if you can see anything on 2013 tfs. That way you'll know if you need to use the [/workspace:workspacename] [/login:username,[password]] switches.  I suspect that tf.exe is not using the login information that you are using with powershell